# Dtype changing when setting a column as an index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am reindexing files from multiple folders.  A file initially looks like this:

```
Combined   Percent
0101       50
0102       25
0104       25
```

I then use this code to create a new index which is the union of the indexes of all my files in a folder:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob 

folders=(r'C:\pathway_to_folders')
for folder in os.listdir(folders): 
    path=os.path.join(folders,folder)
    filenames=glob(os.path.join(path+'/*.csv'))
    def rfile(fn):
        return pd.read_csv(fn, dtype='str', index_col=0)
    dfs = [rfile(fn) for fn in filenames]
    idx = dfs[0].index
    for i in range(1, len(dfs)):
        idx = idx.union(dfs[i].index)
    print idx
```

when I set the column `Combined` as the index column, `dfs` now looks like this:

```
Combined   Percent
101        50
102       25
104       25
```

Is there a way to keep the formatting for the index the same as the original column, or to manipulate my code to not have to set an index possibly?

Comment: It should just work, does `pd.read_csv(fn, dtype={'Combined':str}, index_col=0)` work?

Comment: It does not. Possibly it is because the dataframes are being turned into lists with this line `dfs = [rfile(fn) for fn in filenames]`?

Comment: if you didn't set the index_col does the dtype get preserved? `pd.read_csv(fn, dtype=str)`?

Comment: Yes it does, it only changes when setting the index column.

Comment: I think this is some long standing bug where if you try to specify the dtype and set the index column then it doesn't work, you'd need to do it as a secondary step: `return pd.read_csv(fn, dtype=str).set_index('Combined')`

Comment: Yep, that fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is still a long standing bug where you can't set the dtype and specify the same column as the index column, you have to do this as a secondary step:

```
def rfile(fn):
    return pd.read_csv(fn, dtype=str).set_index('Combined')
```